# Best way to build an SQL Update sentence from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, mysqli

I'm working on a project that require a profil in which people can modify their informations.

It's working but I was wondering : What is the best way to alter a line in a mysql database ? Should I modify value by value or update everything ?

**Example :**
Here I get what the current name and firstname are and I only update when it's different from what is currently on my database

**Example 1 - Value by value**

I made two query for each data if a change is made.

```
  if( (!empty($name)) && ($nom != $name_user) ){ 
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET name_user='$name' WHERE id_user='$id'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo '<h2 class="center">Your name has been modified</h2>';
  }

  if( (!empty($firstname)) && ($firstname!= $firstname_user) ){ 
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET name_user='$name' WHERE id_user='$id'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo '<h2 class="center">Your firstname has been modified</h2>';
  }
```

**Exemple 2 - Everything in one query**

It does the same but only with one query.

```
  if( ((!empty($firstname)) && ($firstname!= $firstname_user)) || ((!empty($firstname)) && ($firstname!= $firstname_user)) ){ 
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET name_user='$name', firstname_user='$firstname' WHERE id_user='$id'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo '<h2 class="center">Your profil has been modified</h2>';
  }
```

Is it better to only update the value when it's actually change ? (example 1)

Is it better to change the two value even though only one was changed ? (example 2 )

What could be the best in performance ? Thank you !

Comment: Update only the values that have changed, and do them all in one query. Also, use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to avoid [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I know about prepared statements, this was just for a quick reading. How do you only use one query, do you use [switch](http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php)  ? Here on my profil I only have two field but maybe I will need more in the future, what do you recommend me to do ? Thanks btw !

Comment: What's the difference, a quick reading or not quick? why you're not using prepared statements for ANY reading as you SHOULD?

Comment: I deleted my answer. Take a look at this, or google for "dynamically bind params mysqli": http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli

Comment: Yep, no my mistake, i'll look at prepared statement, It wasn't what I think it was. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute a single `UPDATE` to modify all necessary fields. There are several ways to build the sentence. This is a basic one:

```
$fields = array("field1", "field2", "field3");
$values = array();

foreach ($fields as $field) 
{
    if (isset($_GET[$field]) AND !empty($_GET[$field]))
    {
        $values[$field] = "$field='"
                         . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET[$field])
                         ."'";
    }    
}
$sql = "UPDATE user SET " . implode (',', $values) . " WHERE id_user='$id'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Note: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for escaping special chars. Details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d3806641b8fd36894bd8a776ebaaaf13f7b0246).

Edited:
If security is a concern, seriously consider using Prepared Statements, as pointed in some comments.

Comment: Very clear and flexible answer, thank you very much !
I will edit my original question because the lack of prepared statement really trigger everyone.

Answer (score -1):

The way I usually handle situations like this is by making the form names match the database field names, then I put a hidden field next to the visible input containing the old value with a modified name;

```
<input type="text" name="aboutme">
<input type="hidden" name="aboutme_old" value="<?= $aboutme ?>">
//$aboutme being the old value of the value to be changed
```

Then on the receiving PHP page use a foreach statement to run through a list of possible fields and create the statement needed.

```
<?php
//Set the fields to check
$fields = array ('firstname', 'secname', 'interests', 'aboutme');

//Start MYSQL query
$mysql_query = 'UPDATE `table` SET ';

$i = 0;
//Run through the list
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $old_field = $field. '_old'; //Set to the old value input name
    $input = cleanInput($_POST[$field]); //cleanInput() is a made up function to check the data.
    if ($i != 0) $mysql_query =. ', '; //Check if you need a comma
    if ($_POST[$field] != $_POST[$old_field]) $mysql_query =. $field. ' = "' $input. '"';
    //Set the query if there is a change
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Make sure the data you are using is checked before you pass it through MYSQL otherwise you risk MYSQL Injection and thats just not good :)

A side note, this potentially would give information to an attacker if they realise your input names are the same as your DB field names. 
But to test that they first have to make it into your DB, which shouldn't be a problem if you have all the relevant safeguards in place.

Best of luck